# Loop no Json [PHP e MYSQL]

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho uma página de visualização de dados de uma tabelado bd, sendo que uma das células dessa tabela em html, é na verdade um loop. Quero fazer a edição inline, que já usei em outros projetos (https://github.com/markcell/jquery-tabledit), mas com todos os campos  fixos. Dessa vez, eu não tenho todos os tds fixos, por exemplo, se uma agencia tiver 10 protocolos, será gerado 10 tds p ela, se tiver 1 será gerado 1 na visualização.

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz de como pegar essas ids?

Parte da visualização da tabela, onde tem o loop

```
                 echo'<td>'.$turno.'</td>';
                 echo'<td>'.$funcionarios.'</td>';
                 echo'<td>'.$qt_col.'</td>';
                 echo'<td>'.$tipo_ocorrencia.'</td>';

   //Busca as qtds de tipos de atividades cadastradas da agência para previstro e realizado
    $dados3 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM protocolos_agencias where id_prot=:id_prot  and tipo_ocorrencia=:tipo and status=1 ");

      $dados3->bindParam(':id_prot',$id_prot, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $dados3->bindParam(':tipo',$tipo_ocorrencia, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $dados3->execute();

         while($table3 = $dados3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

          echo'<td>'.$table3->qtd_atividades.'</td>';
                                    }


                              echo'<td>'.$tempo.'</td>';
```

Script de edição do jquery

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){  
     $('#example5').Tabledit({
      url:'atividade/action.php',
      columns:{
       identifier:[0, 'id_registro'],
       editable:[[2, 'atividade'], [3, 'turno'],[4, 'funcionarios'],[5, 'qtd'],[6, 'tipo'],[7, 'qtd_atividade'],[8,'tempo']]
      },

      restoreButton:false,
       buttons:{
          confirm: {
            class: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger',
            html: 'Desativar?'
        },
         delete:{
            class: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger',
            html: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> &nbsp',
            action: 'delete'
        },

         edit:{
            class: 'btn btn-sm btn-success',
            html: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> &nbsp',
            action: 'edit'
        },

       },
      onSuccess:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
      {
       if(data.action == 'delete')
       {
        $('#'+data.id).remove();
       }
      }
     });

});  


    </script>
```

O erro está aqui: `[7, 'qtd_atividade'],[8,'tempo']]`
pois se eu tiver uma agencia com mais de 1 tipo de atividade, não vai funcionar.

Comment: primeiro. O snippet não suporta linguagem server side. Se puder na tabelam, mostrar o HTML gerado seria mais legal...
Com relação a sua demanda, você poderia jogar um atributo em cada td ou em cada input onde colocaria o id do que quer alterar? Se sim, fica mais fácil, porém trabalhoso...

Comment: @DiegoSantos A tabela é imensa, tem quase uns 30 campos. Por isso, não postei tudo. :D  Por isso, queria fazer o update inline tb p ficar mais agradável p usuario. Assim, o problema é que o <td> tipo de atividade, ele varia de usuário. Então n posso dá uma id fixa, correto?